# How to run protractor with different config file in sequence?

Tags: protractor, gulp-protractor

I have different configuration file for protractor, and I would like to create a gulp task which run protractor for each config file in sequence.
Here is my actual code:

```
gulp.src('conf/protractor.conf.*.js')
      .pipe($.debug())
      .pipe($.foreach(function(stream, file){
        var configFileName = path.join('conf/', path.basename(file.path));

        console.log(configFileName);

        gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.e2e, '/**/*.js'))
            .pipe($.protractor.protractor({
              configFile: configFileName,
              args: args
            }))
            .on('error', function (err) {
              // Make sure failed tests cause gulp to exit non-zero
              console.log('Error catch by gulp');
              throw err;
            })
            .on('end', function () {
              // Close browser sync server
              browserSync.exit();
              done();
              return stream;
            });
      }));
```

it run protractor only with the first configuration file and then stop, even if the different conf file were listed by foreach.

Does anyone has an idea of what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround: instead of trying to use gulp only to do what I want to do, I created a little shell script.
Now, my gulp task take protractor config file path from command line argument like that:

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

if (!argv.conf || typeof argv.conf !== 'string' ) throw new Error('protractor configuration file path required');

function runProtractor (done) {
  gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.e2e, '/**/*.js'))
      .pipe($.protractor.protractor({
        configFile: argv.conf
      }))
      .on('error', function (err) {
        // Make sure failed tests cause gulp to exit non-zero
        throw err;
      })
      .on('end', function () {
        // Close browser sync server
        browserSync.exit();
        done();
      });
}

gulp.task('protractor', ['protractor:src']);
gulp.task('protractor:src', ['serve:e2e', 'webdriver-update'], runProtractor);
```

And I use a shell script to parse my folder and call `gulp protractor` for each configuration file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for filename in conf/protractor.conf.*.js; do
    gulp protractor --conf=$filename
done
```

It works like a charm.